# SVN: excluding a file type from repository but not between 2 machines

Tags: css, svn, repository, less

I am using less to manage a website and since I am the styling curator, these files remain hidden in the repository from the rest of the PCs since no one else needs to edit or modify them (as a security measure, since some proactive persons have edited the css files which gives me some headaches when I compile less without their changes ), since only I should edit and compile them.

But now I'll be needing to share and sync the less and css files with one other person in the newtork, and either my changes or his changes will have to be compiled and synced up: if I update a file, I need SVN to notify him that his version is old and needs to sync up, and viceversa if he's the one who makes changes.

So, since css files are compiled from less files and some of them have dependencies between them, I only need to share them with one coworkers via SVN, and since he is starting with less variables and such, I want to have the option to keep and review logs and preform reverts to previous versions, which effectively means to maintain less files invisible to everyone else in SVN, but one other PC.

Is it possible? If it is, how would that go?

[image: css/less tree]

SVN 1.8

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Can you elaborate what's the real question here? What's your current workflow? Knowing your current workflow will help to advise you howto adjust it.

Comment: Sure, I'll expand on my question. Thanks.

Comment: Show part of your real tree (with less sources in it) and check version of SVN-client: is it at least 1.6

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't have IP-based ACLs (easy), you can get only username-based ACLs
2. This ACLs must be implemented on server-side (and path-based access control must be enabled prior to defining rules)
3. With [Path-Based Authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) you can have enable|disable rules for individual files